# keystore password was incorrect/Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter

Getting this error when building my APK:
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
and
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I've ensured that the password is correct.

Any ideas?

Running the latest stable version of flutter.

Thanks!

```
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
[        ] > A failure occurred while executing
com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
[        ]    > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key from store "C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Fluxstore\android\app\key.jks": keystore password was incorrect
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 16s

[   +5 ms] Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
[        ]
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:411:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      _AndroidBuilderImpl.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_builder.dart:101:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:103:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #17     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #18     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

First please update your sdk (android, dart and flutter)
Next run `flutter clean`
Then run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

Answer (score 0):

Tried that, didn't work out.

I finally got it working by removing Android Studio, SDK, & flutter completely and then reinstalling.

Also, my Android Studio had a whitespace in the installation file path. I installed it to the root drive, which may have helped.